# Attribute validation error for tag CFFILE

Tags: coldfusion

Currently, I have

```
<cfset filedirectoryYear = "E:\FilesSubmitted\"&#form.current_year#&"\"&#form.division#&"\">
<cfif FORM.attachment_1 neq "">
    <cffile action="upload"
        accept="text/plain,application/msword,application/pdf,application/rtf"          
        filefield="attachment_1"
        destination="E:\temp\uploads"
        nameconflict="Makeunique"
    >
    <!--- rename the file and move it to permanent destination --->        
    <cfset submittedfileName =               
        #form.departmentname#&"_"&#form.departmentnumber#&"_"&#form.section_number_1#&"."&#cffile.ClientFileExt#>
    <cfset presentfileName = #cffile.serverFileName#&"."&#cffile.ClientFileExt#>
    <cffile
        action="rename"
        source="E:\temp\uploads\#presentfileName#"
        destination=#filedirectoryYear##submittedfileName#
    >
    <!---   now create a temporary variable for the attachment so that it can be emailed later on --->
    <cfset attachment_local_file_1 =  
        #filedirectoryYear#&#submittedfileName#&#cffile.ClientFileExt#>
</cfif>
<cfset attachment_local_file_1 = #filedirectoryYear#&#submittedfileName#>
```

When I submit, I get the error message

> Attribute validation error for tag CFFILE.

The value of the attribute source, which is currently `E:\temp\uploads\File.pdf`, is invalid and this line is referred. `destination="#filedirectoryYear##submittedfileName#"` from the snippet

```
<cffile
    action="rename"
    source="E:\temp\uploads\#presentfileName#"
    destination=#filedirectoryYear##submittedfileName#
>
```

The `filedirectoryYear` path exists. What could be the issue? I am using ColdFusion 8 on a Windows machine with IIS

Answer (score 0):

You feel CF is pointing to an incorrect destination, however the astute observer will note that the error message is pointing out the "source" as the problem.

Your code claims the source is `E:\temp\uploads\(some variable)`

The error claims the source is `c:\Course Syllabi\uploads\Web Based System Two Page Handout.pdf`

I'd circle back and make certain you are debugging the correct line of code.

Comment: Thanks, but the error message "c:\Course Syllabi\uploads\Web Based System Two Page Handout.pdf" was from another application I was working on which should be ignored for the present question.

Comment: I got it working, the destination directory was not named as value in the CF variable #filedirectory#

Answer (score 0):

For this type of error please check the path of your file this error occur at the case of incorrect destination or source paths

```
check desired folder exist in same path
check Root Directory mean site URL is it correct 
print the path and verify it with your directory surely there will be  any conflict remove it that's why this error arising
```